# sqlite delete row by timestamp < x days

Tags: sqlite, datetime, delete-row

My table looks like this:

```
 tx.executeSql(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
      msg_id UNSIGNED INT PRIMARY KEY ASC, 
      msg_when DATETIME, 
      msg_read INTEGER, 
      title TEXT, msg_text TEXT
     )",
```

I add records using this query:

```
 tx.executeSql(
   "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mytable
    (msg_id, msg_when, msg_read, title, msg_text)
    VALUES 
    (?,?,?,?,?)",
```

I want to delete rows that are over 'x' days old and I'm using this query but nothing gets deleted, the success callback is being called with no rows effected.

```
 tx.executeSql(
   "DELETE FROM mytable 
    WHERE msg_when <= datetime('now', '-? days')", [days],
```

I've also tried:

```
var strQuery = "DELETE FROM mytable 
   WHERE msg_when <= datetime('now', '-" +days +" days')";
tx.executeSql(strQuery,
```

and:

```
var strQuery = "DELETE FROM mytable 
  WHERE msg_when <= datetime('now', '-4 days')";
tx.executeSql(strQuery,
```

The data looks like:

```
json: {"status":"OK"
 ,"count":1
 ,"msg_id":"94"
 ,"when":"2016-08-23 11:21:01"
 ,"alerts":[
   {"msg_id":"44"
    ,"title":"Medical Emergency"
    ,"text":"Heart Attack"
    ,"msg_when":"2016-08-05 14:52:03"
   }
  ]
 }
```

Other than deleting rows by date, everything is working perfectly fine.  Any suggestions on what I can do to fix the delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there's actually two tricks to solving this.

First, if you declare your field as a datetime (which is nothing more than an integer) you will NEVER get this to work.  Not under iOS 9.x, not under Android and not on Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) on Windows 10.

What you have to do is store your date as a TEXT field and store your datetime as a string like this:

```
 tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (msg_id UNSIGNED INT PRIMARY KEY ASC, msg_when TEXT, msg_read INTEGER, title TEXT, msg_text TEXT)",
```

Next, you have to wrap your comparison in (parenthesis) so that sqlite treats it as a formula and does the math conversions for you... like this:

```
tx.executeSql(DELETE FROM mytable WHERE (msg_when <= datetime('now', '-4 days'))",
```

Notice the parenthesis before the (msg_when column and after the closing parenthesis on the datetime)) function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `DELETE` statement is that the parameter template (`?`) is within the string literal and is therefore ignored. You need to use the concatenation operator (`||`):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE msg_when <= datetime('now', '-' || ? || ' days')
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. As an FYI, I've also tried: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE msg_when <= datetime('now', '-" +days +" days') and that builds the correct string (in my case '-4 days' but I have msgs that are 3+ weeks old

Comment: If it's not working, you will need to include some sample data in your question. Be aware that date/times are stored in SQLite as ISO 8601 strings and that is what the `date` function returns. If your data is not in that format, it won't work. Note that SQLite will **not** enforce the format - just as it will not enforce column types, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The datetime is exactly as passed from mysql as a json string 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' famously called msg_when. ;-) They query and display as such.

Comment: With the obvious error corrected, if your question is to be useful to others it will need to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your suggestion, while informative, didn't solve the problem.  I added other methods that I have tried and a data example to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM AIS WHERE timpstamp < datetime('now', '-1 minutes')

this should work, if not then check the table where timestamp is saved,
check the format of the time string, it should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS , if your forfamt doesnt match, the command will not work.

Save the timestamp using SQLite, not using system command.